# Ember.js different views if login

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm trying out [Ember.js](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SproutCore) (previously SproutCore). How can I change the view after an API call?

```
App.userController = Ember.ArrayController.create({
    loadUser: function () {
        var self = this;
        $.post("/api/user/auth/", {user:'user',password:'pass'},function(user,code){
            if (code == 'success') {
                App.User.create(user);
            }
        });
    }
});
App.userController.loadUser();
```

My view:

```
<script type='text/x-handlebars'>
    <div class='span10'>
        {{#if App.user }}
            <h1>User</h1>
        {{else}}
            <h1>no User </h1>
        {{/if}}
    </div>
</script>
```

It will run the `#if App.user` before I get a response from the Ember code. Can I somehow change the view if I got a user from the call?

Comment: If you could please provide a jsFiddle with your issue I'd be more than happy to look at it for you. You can [use this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ud3323/8Z2Fc/) as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I have enough details in your question, but I think what you want to do is this:

```
if (code == 'success') {
    App.user = App.User.create(user);
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Add this to your ApplicationController:

```
layout :layout_switcher

private

def layout_switcher
  user_signed_in? ? 'application' : 'logged_out'
end
```

Comment: Um, a ruby answer to a javascript question?